# Error : Unable to start png() device

Tags: r

I am using Windows. When trying to plot a graph on png device, it fails with the error.

My code:

```
png("C:\\plot1.png", width = 480, height = 480, units = "px", bg = "white")

par(mar= c(4, 4, 2, 1))

hist(pwrcon$Global_active_power,col = "red", main = "Global Active Power", xlab = "Global Active Power (kilowatts)")

dev.off()
```

Error:

```
Error in png("C:\\plot1.png", width = 480, height = 480, units = "px",  : 
  unable to start png() device
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In png("C:\\plot1.png", width = 480, height = 480, units = "px",  :
  unable to open file 'C:\plot1.png' for writing
2: In png("C:\\plot1.png", width = 480, height = 480, units = "px",  :
  opening device failed
```

Can anyone help me in getting this resolved?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @R.Schifini, did you add additional backslashes when editing?  If so (and if your diagnosis below is correct), you have made this question very confusing ...

Comment: @BenBolker, I only formatted the code. I agree that it is confusing, but I recall only seeing one backslash. It seems that the problem was solved by reinstalling. I would vote for the whole question to be removed since it doesn't seem to be of further use. (edit: I even copied the original path and filename)

Comment: OK, voting to close.

Comment: Yes, most likely this error is caused by a wrong or non-exist folder directory in the `filename` that we try to write the png. The folder we plan to use should be created in advance (using e.g. `if(!dir.exist(folder_name) dir.create(folder_name)`).

Answer (score 29):

I cannot explain why, but I once found that when the folder path in which my RStudio project was saved was a very long character string, the png device would fail. When I shortened the folder path it worked.

Comment: Not sure if it's still the case now, but for many years, the number of characters in a Windows path + file name could not exceed 255 or so.

Comment: This also worked for me. (Windows 2019 Server, version: 1809 from oct2022).

Answer (score 15):

I had the same issue while working in an r-markdown document.

The issue in my case had something to do with viewing the Chunk Output Inline. When I switched to viewing the Chunk Output in Console, it worked just fine.

Comment: Finally a solution that also works for me!! All the other solutions on multiple similar questions here at StackOverflow on lengthy work directory paths are not the problem if you have a filename like "Rplot%03d.png". This solution seems to be specific for Rmd files and viewing chunk output in console can be done in the wheel next to your knit button.

Answer (score 11):

I got also this error: "Error in (function (filename = "Rplot%03d.png", width = 480, height = 480,  : 
  unable to start png() device"

The name of the .Rmd file that I've been working on was containing some nonenglish characters, so removing them has been helpful in my case.

Comment: This is actually what solved my problem, thanks so much!

Answer (score 8):

Had the same problem on a PC. The problem was that there was an antivirus program with "Safe files" enabled, which blocked Rstudio from creating graphics files. The antivirus didn't display any information when blocking, so it doesn't give you any clues really.

Comment: How did you figure it out?

Answer (score 5):

The filename `C:\plot1.png` contains a backslash (`\`) which is an escape character . This causes the error you are getting.

Change it to a slash (`/`)

```
png("C:/plot1.png", width = 480, height = 480, units = "px", bg = "white")
```

Or double the backslash (`\\`):

```
png("C:\\plot1.png", width = 480, height = 480, units = "px", bg = "white")
```

Comment: I am using "C:\\" in the program. Tried replacing with "C:/". Still the same error.

Comment: I tried re-installing rstudio and it did help. Now the code seems to work. Thank you R.Schifini.

Comment: I had the *exact* same problem today.
The problem is that I tried two things to correct is, so I don't know which one worked:
In my here statement 'here::i_am(path = "inst/A.Rmd"  )'    I mistakenly had a previous version of the name there. However, the document knit to html quite nicely.

Second, I shortened the name of the project directly and RMarkdown file name each to 'A'.  I was worried about path links, since I saw that the .png files were stored in a sub-directly with a very long name, based on the RMarkdown file name.

One or both fixed the problems.

Comment: i had the same issue, but with the forward slash in the filename.  changing it to a dash fixed the issue

Answer (score 3):

I added "dev.off()
"before plot, the problem solved. The reason may be because of the previous device has not turn off yet.

Answer (score 3):

I received the error mentioned above

`Error in (function (filename = "Rplot%03d.png", width = 480, height = 480, : unable to start png() device Calls: <Anonymous> ...`

My issue was with the fig.width option in one of my R-code chunks of my R-markdown document and when the output was rendered as an html document. The fig.width was too large compared to the other fig.width options in other code-chunks. Again this was observed only when I attempted to render it as an html document, not as a powerpoint presentation.

Answer (score 2):

Also met the similar issue in Windows 10, my R script is put in the same folder as `RScript.exe`, using the package `ggplot2`. However I got the message `could not open file 'Rplot001.png'`.

Finally found two ways to solve the problem:

1. Move the R script to any other folder except the folder `RScript.exe` located.
2. Set work directory using the command `setwd("YourPath")` first, then do other things.

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same type of error, neither png nor jpg device could not open from ggplot2's ggsave command. The path contained an Å symbol which was stored as \305 when inserted in a variable describing the directory.

`setwd(path)` followed by `ggsave(filename)`for this directory variable did work in this case, but `ggsave(paste(path, filename, sep="/")` did not.

Replacing the Å with an A in my case could resolve the error.

Answer (score 1):

One other problem could be that your Rstudio may have updated. I have encountered this problem while working inside R-markdown. Trying the code in a regular R script still works. Try saving the markdown as a new file. This should fix the problem temporarily.

Do not know of a long term solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message. Turns out there was a typo in the path name. 
Besides these problems, reinstalling ggplot and tydiverse from CRAN seemed to have worked for some, see [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/error-in-grdevices-png/4816)

Answer (score 1):

The error **usually** means that the file cannot over accessed or overwritten, meaning **that the file is in use** or the **file path is not writeable**.

In the first case, just close the files you have open (e.g., in an image preview) and try again.

Comment: Such errors also appear if both is not the case ...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Please read the bold parts, especially the first one :) I do not say that it cannot happen for another reason. I only say that it usually/often/probably happens because of the reason I state.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this error today when working in an RMarkdown notebook (it was fine yesterday).  If I edit a chunk then try to run it I get this error.  If I then save the notebook and try the chunk again it works.  My working directory is a OneDrive folder.  I wonder whether that may be an issue.

Having to save every after edit is not ideal, but a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved, but I thought I might add my answer if it makes someone's life easier.
Of course you can have your `wd` set to some short path (or path with no special characters): `setwd("c/Users/John/My_r_project)`
But I use R at work, thus my R project is saved on a common drive with super long path, and my working directory has to be long. A workaround was:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
    fig.path = "c/Users/John/My_r_project/figures" #make sure you create the folder first in Windows
)
```
````

And you can of course add other options there as well, such as: `dpi = 300`, `echo = FALSE`, ...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while running R in Jupyter notebook. I did a lot of Google searches and tried everything possible. The only way it worked for me was by restarting the kernel. But, restarting the kernel is not a good solution if you already have trained your models which took you a long time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to save the PNG image, make sure you have permission to create files in the destination folder. I've seen this error come up on a corporate network where full access had not been granted to the user.

Answer (score 0):

interestingly, also observed the error when in the UI 'tableOutput' was used and on the server side 'renderPlot'

Answer (score 0):

Have noticed an "unable to start png() device"-error on Windows when using the character `:` more than once in the string for `filename`, regardless of the `nchar` of the string (up to the permitted maximum of 511 `nchar`).

Answer (score 0):

I also had this error message, but with with `Hmis::HTML()`

> Error in .External2 ... unable to start png() device

Turns out the solution is to set the Graphics Backend in the Global Options to Cairo or AGG, or set `options(bitmapType="cairo")` or similar in your ~.Rprofile.

```
options(bitmapType="cairo")
```

Ref: https://community.rstudio.com/t/missing-x11-support-in-rstudio/174814

Answer (score -1):

I once also run into this problem. For me the first solution worked, but you might also want to check the other two options.

1. Restart R session. Tab Session > Restart R (Ctrl + Shift + F10)
2. Check working directory using [getwd()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/getwd) and change it is necessary using setwd(path)
3. Don't forget to close the device using dev.off()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

I have seen this message, and find this is because the png file is occupied by another software or process.

So close the software or process, then restart rstudio.