# What is this error; "Error in (function (filename = "Rplot%03d.png", width = 480, height = 480, : unable to start png() device"?

Tags: r

Whenever I use ggplot2 I get following the same error

```
x2012 <- data.frame(readRDS(file = "Exercises05/x2012_1_6cleaned10.Rda"))

i <- 1

while (i<=250){
  x2012[[i,1]] <- mean(sample(nrow(x2012), 25, replace = FALSE))
  i = i+1
}

mean(x2012$sumtotprice)
sd(x2012$sumtotprice)

library("tidyverse")

ggplot(x2012, aes(sumtotprice)) +
  geom_density()
```

> Error in (function (filename = "Rplot%03d.png", width = 480, height =
>   480, : unable to start png()

The dataset is irrelevant, I always get this error.

Thank you for your time, and apologies for not providing a more general example!

Comment: Did you try with like a simple inbuilt dataset. Just to rule out whether that's the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45113597

Comment: Possibly: https://community.rstudio.com/t/unable-to-initiate-png-device-rnotebook/3658/3 or https://community.rstudio.com/t/error-in-grdevices-png/4816/15

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is related to path length limits in Windows. When rendering outputs 'inline' in the RMD it seems it occurs via a tmp directory that throws an error because its parent path is too long. However, if you just change the options so that the output is in the console rather than inline by adding

```
editor_options: 
  chunk_output_type: console
```

at the top of the document it seems to fix it for me. This can also be accomplished in the menu that drops down from the gear icon at the top of the source pane in RStudio.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the response,

In the thread (stackoverflow.com/q/45113597) posted by r2evans, I found following solution:

Saving the markdown as a new file will fix the problem temporarily, however, I do not know of a long term solution.