# Unable to export plot: R code execution error/ unable to start png() device

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics, export, png

Strangely enough, I'm not able to export the following plot:

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point()
```

1. I have tried to save it manually,  via plot->export->save as image. But then a windows pops up saying 'R code execution error'. Only exporting the plot as **.svg** works, but I need a **PNG** or **JPEG**.
2. I have tried saving the plot via `ggsave("mtcars.png")`, however, this gives the following error:

```
Error in grDevices::png(..., res = dpi, units = "in") : 
  unable to start png() device
```

---

Session info:

```
R version 4.0.1 (2020-06-06)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)
```

Comment: Try changing the saving path (with ggsave path parameter) and see what happens. According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/58773897/11626803 long paths could be the problem.

Comment: I have tried a new path from my desktop including only 26 characters, but unfortunately this did not solve the problem.

Comment: Be sure that the path does not contain special characters.

Comment: When using ```ggsave("plot.png")``` in a new project, the same error occurs...

Comment: Reinstalling Rstudio solved the problem. I think the way in which the graphic devices were set up was causing the problems.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I couldn't save any plot, neither manually nor with the ggsave function. In my case it was the antivirus (Avast) blocking R from saving the image, so I had to modify the permissions there.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30265673)