# Rmarkdown knitting fails with "unable to start png() device" error

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have other plots that I had knitted but I get an error with this particular one. I changed the plot format from png to pdf yet it is still giving me the same problem.

```
processing file: BellaBeat_data_analysis_Report.Rmd
  |..........|  95% [Question 2. How do daily step counts correlate with daily calories burned?]               
Quitting from lines 410-447 [Question 2. How do daily step counts correlate with daily calories burned?] (BellaBeat_data_analysis_Report.Rmd)
Error in `png()`:
! unable to start png() device
Backtrace:
  1. rmarkdown::render(...)
  2. knitr::knit(knit_input, knit_output, envir = envir, quiet = quiet)
  3. knitr:::process_file(text, output)
  8. knitr:::process_group.block(group)
  9. knitr:::call_block(x)
     ...
 18. base::mapply(...)
 19. knitr (local) `<fn>`(...)
 22. knitr:::plot2dev(...)
 24. knitr (local) `<fn>`(...)
 25. grDevices::png(..., res = dpi, units = "in")
Warning messages:
1: In png(..., res = dpi, units = "in") :
  unable to open file 'BellaBeat_data_analysis_Report_files/figure-html/Question 2. How do daily step counts correlate with daily calories burned?-1.png' for writing
2: In png(..., res = dpi, units = "in") : opening device failed
                                                                                                                                                                                      
Execution halted
```

Comment: See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45113597/17303805) for some possible solutions.