# error in png() Rmarkdown Word with Plumber API

Tags: r, r-markdown, plumber

I am creating a Plumber API to generate a MS Word document with images, however, I get the following error in Swagger

```
"message": "\u001b[1m\u001b[33mError\u001b[39m in `png()`:\u001b[22m\n\u001b[33m!\u001b[39m unable to start png() device\n"
```

This is my plumber function `plumber.R`

```
#* @serializer contentType list(type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")
#* @get /word
function(team){
  tmp <- getwd()
  
  render("test_report.Rmd", tmp, output_format = "word_document",
         params = list(team = team))

  readBin(paste0(tmp, ".docx"), "raw", n=file.info(paste0(tmp, ".docx"))$size)
}
```

This is the Rmd file `test_report.Rmd`

````
---
title: test
output: html_document
params:
  team: NA
---

`r params$team`

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

```{r, echo=FALSE}
 plot(pressure)
```
````

To run the API

```
library(plumber)
library(rmarkdown)
pr("plumber.R") %>%
       pr_run(port=8000)
```

I am using the correct serializer, as without including the `plot()` the API works. What is the problem?

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/q/45113597/3358272

Comment: I'll be surprised if it is anything else, but is `capabilities()["png"]` true?

Comment: @r2evans yes, `capabilities()["png"]` returns TRUE